# How to increment dates by 7 every 7 rows in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a helper column where the date increments by 7 every 7 rows. After looking around, I found the formula below but have not been able to figure out how to modify it to get what I want:

`=DATE(YEAR($A$2),MONTH($A$2),DAY($A$2)+INT((ROW()-7)/7))`

I know the last 7 increments every 7 rows but I cannot figure out how to increment the actual date by 7 using this formula.

Column B is what the output should look like.

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: Hint: Use `MOD()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use the `MOD` function.

Type this formula into cell `B2` and drag down as necessary:

```
= A2-MOD(A2,7)
```

See below.

[image]

Comment: This resulted in giving me the date represented as a number. The output for this specific formula was 42287. Also, it wasn't incrementing by 7.

Comment: @techscolasticus The number you are seeing is Excel's serial number dating system. The result is correct, you just need to format the cell as a date.

Comment: I know that's a serial number but it's not incrementing by 7 every 7 rows

Comment: Nvm...I don't know why but it took a while for Excel to show the increments. Thanks!

Comment: @techscolasticus That formula is giving me the exact desired result from your image in your original question. See above, I edited my post to show the results I am getting.

Comment: @techscolasticus Great! You should mark this answer as correct by placing a checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

Your formula references only A2 so if you don't want dates in A3:An a version of your attempt may suit (in B2 and copied down):

```
=DATE(YEAR($A$2),MONTH($A$2),DAY($A$2)+7*INT((ROW()-2)/7))
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate approach